# Codeigniter custom URL Routing

Tags: codeigniter, url, custom-url

I have a URL in my Codeigniter

`http://localhost:64743/index.php/mybox?name=John`

I want it to look something like this

```
http://localhost:64743/index.php/mybox/name/John
```

is it posiible? how does custom URL works in CodeIgniter?

Comment: Look at user guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is just a matter of setting up a controller method and parameter.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $route['mybox/(:any)'] = "mybox/index";
```

user above mention code in routes.php of config folder and you will get query string value by $this->uri->segment(3); and $this->uri->seggment(4);

for further assistance, please check

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html